# Conda UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 24-25

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
running develop
E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running egg_info
writing improved_diffusion.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to improved_diffusion.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to improved_diffusion.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to improved_diffusion.egg-info\top_level.txt
file improved_diffusion.py (for module improved_diffusion) not found
reading manifest file 'improved_diffusion.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'improved_diffusion.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating e:\anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\improved-diffusion.egg-link (link to .)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Haowe\OneDrive\æ¡Œé\x9d¢\Research\Diffusion-LM-main\improved-diffusion\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    setup(
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 987, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 34, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\develop.py", line 126, in install_for_development
    f.write(self.egg_path + "\n" + self.setup_path)
  File "E:\Anaconda\envs\dlm\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 24-25: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried to set encoding variable but it didnt work. The import os and set variable is also not working. Can someone help me with this please? Thank you so much! This is running on Anaconda, Python 3.9.13.